# Socket.io creating multiple connections on page refresh

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I am making a chatroom but after each page refresh, more connections are made. For example, if I go to my chat room page, only one connection is created. However, after I refresh once, 2 clients are now connected. After each page refresh, one more connection is added.

here is my chat route

```
    /* GET home page. */
router.get('/', accessControl.ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  const io = req.app.io;
  console.log('const io created');
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(' %s sockets connected', io.engine.clientsCount);
    console.log('[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has connected');
    socket.on('chat message', function(message){
      if (message.sessionID == req.session.id) {
        io.emit('chat message', message);
        console.log('message: ' + message.message);
      } else {
        console.log('client sessionID ('+message.sessionID+') does not match server sessionID ('+req.session.id+')');
      }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has disconnected');
      socket.disconnect();
    });
  });

  res.render('chat/index', {
    title: "Chat",
    //send session id for client verification
    sessionID: req.session.id,
  });
});
```

the output after refreshing the chat page 3 times:

```
const io created
1 sockets connected
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has connected
const io created
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has disconnected
1 sockets connected
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has connected
1 sockets connected
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has connected
const io created
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has disconnected
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has disconnected
1 sockets connected
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has connected
1 sockets connected
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has connected
1 sockets connected
[NodeApp] (socket.io) A client has connected
message: test message (should be sent 3 times)
message: test message (should be sent 3 times)
message: test message (should be sent 3 times)
```

Comment: Did you wait long enough to see if the prior connections close down after a short while?  It is normal for a refresh to close the prior connection and then open a new one.  In some circumstances, there might be a delay before the prior one closes.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, I waited 5 minutes after the last page refresh but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){...}
```

inside a route handler.  Every time that route is hit, you create yet another listener for the event, so they pile up with lots of duplicates and thus you process each message multiple times in all those duplicate event handlers.

You need to put that outside any route handler.  The socket.io server and its listeners needs to be configured when you configured your socket.io server, not in a route handler.

Comment: but then I cannot access req.app.io

Comment: @bena - You can `req.app.io.emit()` from within the request handler.  Not sure what else you're trying to do with `req.app.io`.    At the top level of your module, you already have `app`, so you can use `app.io` there.

Comment: I moved the socket connection and listener to my app.js but now I am not able to `if (message.sessionID == req.session.id) `

Comment: @bena - If you want help with that kind of stuff, then write a new question that describes what you're trying to accomplish (not how you're trying to do it).  When you get a socket.io message, there is no `req` in process at that moment so it isn't clear what you're trying to do at all.  If you want access to the http session from a socket.io message, there are NPM modules that let you do that like express-socket.io-session.  Please continue this in a new question.